# Entry виджет в Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем доброго времени суток. Недавно начал программировать, в питоне совсем ламер. Хочу написать десктопный чат с клиентом и сервером на протоколе tcp/ip, добавив интерфейс на основе tkinter.

Проблема в следующем:
Необходимо считать хост и порт из окна ввода, но при запуске программы данные не считываются.

```py
def get_address():
    HOST = entry1.get()
    PORT = entry2.get()

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chatter")

# Sockets
HOST, PORT = "", ""
label1 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Host:")
label2 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Port:")
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(top)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(top)
button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send")
button.bind("<Button-1>", get_address())

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)
```

С консоли, разумеется, ввод работает, но хочется запихать его в окно

```py
HOST = input('Enter host: ')
PORT = input('Enter port: ')
if not PORT:
PORT = 33000
else:
PORT = int(PORT)

BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(ADDR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получать данные с поля `Entry` вы можете также использовать параметр `textvariable` - переменную, в которую будут сохранятся введенные данные. Я написал рабочий код ниже. Еще я убрал `bind`, заменив его на параметр `command`, так как это удобней. Но вы можете вернуть `bind`, если вам так больше нравится.

P.S. Все таки у Entry есть метод `get`. Но я оставлю этот код здесь, как пример другой реализации.

```
import tkinter

def get_address():
    global HOST
    global PORT
    HOST = host.get()
    PORT = port.get()

top = tkinter.Tk()
top.title("Chatter")

# Sockets
HOST, PORT = "", ""
host, port = tkinter.StringVar(), tkinter.StringVar()

label1 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Host:")
label2 = tkinter.Label(top, text="Port:")
entry1 = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=host)
entry2 = tkinter.Entry(top, textvariable=port)
button = tkinter.Button(top, text="Send", command=get_address)

label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: "насколько я знаю, у виджетов нет метода get" - вы ошибаетесь, у `Entry` есть метод `get`. Если сомневаетесь - лучше проверять.

Comment: Да, да, да. Уже исправил

Answer (score 1):

В этой строке:

```
button.bind("<Button-1>", get_address())
```

вы сразу вызываете функцию `get_address`, а ее результат передаете в метод `bind`. Нужно передавать привязываемую функцию-обработчик не вызывая ее (без скобок):

```
button.bind("<Button-1>", get_address)
```